# Changing immutable object in class

Tags: java, immutability

I have been doing some tutorial videos on Youtube, and one thing that got my interest is that after declaring an immutable class variable we can still change in the methods.

```
private final static List<Object> someList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And after I have instantiated  this "someList" variable, I can still add some data to it. Can someone explain why can we do it, since we declared it final it should be immutable

Comment: You are mixing up final with immutable. They are different. Final = Variable cannot be reassigned to something else, immutable = Object cannot be changed. If you want an Immutable List you can use `Arrays.asList();` for example.

Comment: My bad. I am still learning Java and maybe don’t know all the differences

Comment: Thank you Emre Acar, that answered my question